# Adding An UITableViewController on to a SubView

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

An `UITableViewController` pretty much takes up the entire view. I need a way to limit its height, width and add some shadows etc. For a clear explanation, I won't show the `UITableViewController`'s contents.

Without the use of a storyboard, I subviewed the `UITableViewController`:

```
// In another UIViewController

let otherController = OtherController() // A subclass of UITableViewController
let otherControllerView = otherController.view

someView.addSubView(otherControllerView)

[...] // bunch of constraints
```

Notes:

In `AppDelegate`, if I set the `rootController` as `OtherController()`, everything works as it should. If I change it back to `SomeView()`, I see my modified tableView. If I should click it, it disappears.

[This was the only thing that came close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892974/uitableview-disappearing-content) to my issue but sadly, I could not understand the answers provided as nothing made any sense to me.

I need to understand, why it disappears when touched etc.

`view.bringSubviewToFront(...)` proved futile. I'm gessing that a tableView should be rendered in its own controller and not in another view?

Comment: Why not use a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`?

Comment: Perhaps I could but eventually, I will need an `UITableViewController`

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: Sorry. You're right. I was reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623641/uitableview-vs-uitableviewcontroller. Ive always used `UIViewController`. Ok, I'll give it a go. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So just to answer this question, indeed you got two options. One is the best way, as suggested by Rakesha. Just use `UITableView`. Add it as a subview. Done.

And in the future, if you really want any **controller** to be added onto any `UIView`, remember you need to **add that controller as a child**. For example, in your case:

The controller of the view that will hold your `UITableViewController` will add such `UITableViewController` as a child.

```
self.addChild(yourUITableViewController)
self.whatEverViewContainer.addSubview(yourUITableViewController.view) 
// Take note of the view of your tableViewController above^.
// Then setup the constraints of your yourUITableViewController.view below.
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! Yes! and many yeses! Both answers work but my preference, I rather this approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You must add the instance of `UITableViewController`'s subclass as child view controller of the other view controller. You need to ensure few points in order to make it work. The points are as listed below:

1. Create the instance of your `TableViewController`
2. Add it as a child view controller of the other view controller
3. Add its view as a subview of the desired view (you may do these steps in `viewDidLaod` since they need to be done only once)
4. Keeping in mind the view cycle of a view controller. You must keep a weak reference of the child view controller aka `TableViewController` to adjust its view frame after the parent view controller has laid its subviews.

Code here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let vc = TableViewController()
    addChildViewController(vc)
    view.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    childVC = vc
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    childVC?.view.frame = view.frame
}
```